# Convert Unicode To ASCII in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, unicode, ascii

In c#, I have `ö` ASCII character `148`. but when I change like

```
 char convstr = (char)148;
```

It returns `\u0094`. Its `"”"`.Its unicode.

If I want it back ASCII code, I just use `Strings.Asc("”")`. It will return to 148.

**So How can I get from "”" to 148 in JavaScript?**

I tried Like that=>

`"”".charCodeAt(0)` but it return `8221`. I think its Unicode.

And If you don't mind, please explain to me why `char convstr = (char)148;` return `\u0094` also. I am also stuck in there.

=================================

Comment: .NET strings and characters are *Unicode* - UTF16 to be precise. If you have `ö`, you already have a Unicode character and no conversion is necessary. This page proves this - SO is an ASP.NET site. 148 is *not* an ASCII value anyway. US-ASCII is 7-bit, so valid valued are 0-127. The value 148 comes from a specific codepage, probably 1252. Where does `148` come from? Is it a single byte value? File input? It's easy to convert the bytes to Unicode strings with `Encoding.GetString(byte[])` as long as you know the encoding

Comment: Then use the correct encoding.  Once you use the wrong encoding it is not possible to fix.  ASCII is the same for all encoding for the character 0x00 to 0x7F.  Encoding for characters maps up to 128 unicode characters to the ASCII codes 0x80 to 0xFF.  When you use the wrong encoding you convert a character to the wrong unicode character and then have to map the wrong unicode character back to the correct character.  It is just easier to start from the beginning and use the correct encoding.

Comment: Note that *by definition* any character code greater than 127 CANNOT be ASCII.

Comment: @MatthewWatson,148 is possible for extended ASCII Code? http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @Loran that's not ASCII and not even the common Latin 1 codepage (1252). Where did this value come from? .NET can handle non-Unicode encodings easily, but you have to explain where this came from

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Check my update.

Comment: @Loran you assumed the wrong encoding then. What is the *question* anyway? How to properly represent `ö` or why 148 results in a different character in different codepages?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, So `”`  character is saved in DB and I would like to get it back 1 in javascript.

Comment: @Loran PS transposition isn't encryption. Breaking this is trivial as the letter frequencies remain the same. If you want to encrypt anything, using one of the encryption classes

Comment: @Loran in that case you stored a bad value in the database. Since databases *don't* use 437 (it's *not* the common "ASCII" codepage) you risk losing data due to codepage conversions. The very same problem that occured now

Comment: @Loran databases either store Unicode strings, or strings with an encoding specified through the column's collation. This means that passing non-Unicode data encoded in a different encoding results in a codepage conversion or bad data. With values that *can't* be represented in the target encoding, this can even result in data loss. Instead of a `”` you could get `?` or `�` the replacement characters used in conversion errors.

Comment: Hex value 0094 is equal to decimal value 148

Answer (score 1):

148 isn't the value for `ö` in ASCII (ie the 7-bit US ASCII encoding that goes only up to 127) nor the commonly-referred-to-as-ASCII codepages [1252 (Windows Latin 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). 1252 has `”` in that location while the ISO codepage has nothing. That value is used for `ö` only in the *old* DOS codepages, 437 and 865.

Windows, .NET and C# strings are Unicode natively. This pages proves this - StackOverflow is an ASP.NET site. You can convert data in non-Unicode encodings easily, either through the `Encoding` class, or by specifying the encoding when loading data from streams with a StreamReader.

For example, this will convert the byte value 148 to `ö` using the 437 codepage :

```
var result=Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetString(new byte[]{148});
Debug.Assert(result=="ö");
```

While this returns `”`:

```
var result=Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new byte[]{148});
```

The [StreamReader(string,Encoding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) overload and its variants can load data from files using the specified encoding, eg :

```
using(var reader=new StreamReader(path,Encoding.GetEncoding(437)))
{
    var line=reader.ReadLine();
    ....
}
```